# get data from angular.module config to the corresponding controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, config

I have the following configuration, I have a config where a url is called using $http.get method and the data is stored in a variable "alpha". How do I access this variable from the controller. I tried to inject $rootScopeProvider into the config and tried to set $rootScope.pqr = alpha. This gives an error. How do I do it?

```
angular.module('thisApp', [someDependencies]).config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider) {
    $http.get('url').then(function(response) {
        var alpha = response.data; // i need to access this data in the controller
    )};
}).directive('pqrTitle', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {

        // I need to access alpha here
    });
});
```

How do I do this?

Comment: How are you accessing `$http` from your config block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ui-router-extras, you can use $futureStateProvider for this, you could also use $rootScope and access it in the controller

```
angular.module('thisApp', [someDependencies])
.config( function($futureStateProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider) {

    $futureStateProvider.addResolve(['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
        $http.get('url').then(function(response) {
            $rootScope.alpha = response.data;
        )};
    }]);
})
```

1) in the controller, you should inject rootScope and access the variable. Read this up to understand the [$futureStateProvider in ui-router extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future)

2) if you do not want to use rootScope, make a service and inject it into teh $futureStateProvider.addResolve, set the variable in the service. After that you can get the variable value through a getter function

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Actually I am wondering how you got the `$http` service in the configuration phase too. You can only configure providers and load constants in that phase according to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. **Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services** before they have been fully configured.

When I try to inject a service into a config phase I get the following error: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$http).

Best thing to do is to write a service to get the information from the server you want and inject that service into your directive. (And on the other places you need it)

Example: ([working](http://plnkr.co/edit/JsVjDVmjk37YyQ58W2m8?p=preview) example is more extensive)

```
.controller('TestController', function(alphaService) {
  var self = this;

  self.alpha = alphaService.get().success(function(data) {
    self.alpha = data;
  });
})

.factory('alphaService', function($http) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      return $http.get('url');
    }
  };
})

.directive('myDir', function(alphaService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.alpha = null;

      alphaService.get().success(function(data) {
        scope.alpha = data;
      });
    },
    templateUrl: 'mydir.html'
  };
});
```